# MySQL: Unable to create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I'm working on my first MySQL database for an assignment at my university. Unfortunately I've been stuck for a while trying to create the actual tables with foreign keys between them.

This is the error that the MySQL Workbench forward engineering wizard gives:

Executing SQL script in server

```
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'test.fremført' (errno: 150)    

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Fremført` (    
  `Plate` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `Verk` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Artist` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Dato` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Plate`, `Verk`, `Artist`) ,
  INDEX `Fremført->Artist_idx` (`Artist` ASC) ,
  INDEX `Fremført->Spor_idx` (`Plate` ASC, `Verk` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `Fremført->Artist`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Artist` )
    REFERENCES `Artist` (`ArtistNavn` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Fremført->Spor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Plate` , `Verk` )
    REFERENCES `Spor` (`Verk` , `Verk` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with the above script, and if so have a solution?

Thanks!

edit:
This is the requested spor query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Spor` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Spor` (
  `Plate` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Verk` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Spilletid` DECIMAL(3,2) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Plate`, `Verk`) ,
  INDEX `Plate_idx` (`Plate` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `Plate`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Plate` )
    REFERENCES `Plate` (`KatalogNr` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Artist` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Artist` (
  `ArtistNavn` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  `Artistcol` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ArtistNavn`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Post `CREATE TABLE Spor` and `CREATE TABLE Artist`. Usually, Err150 means that there is a data type mismatch between the primary and related table.  This is also suspect: `REFERENCES Spor (Verk , Verk )`  Perhaps should be `(Plate, Verk)`?

Comment: First post updated with the spor and artist queries. I've tried changing ø to o, but that wasn't the problem it seemed.

I've uploaded the complete script to http://pastebin.com/ZFPiqFUs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

errno150 is very often related to a mismatch between the data types of the primary and related column.  They must match exactly, including character length.

I see a data type mismatch between `Fremført.artist` (`VARCHAR(45)`) and `Artist.ArtistNavn` (`VARCHAR(30)`).  These must be the same for the FOREIGN KEY constraint to succeed.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Fremført` (    
  `Plate` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `Verk` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  /* Must match the primary table VARCHAR(30) */
  `Artist` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  `Dato` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Plate`, `Verk`, `Artist`) ,
  INDEX `Fremført->Artist_idx` (`Artist` ASC) ,
  INDEX `Fremført->Spor_idx` (`Plate` ASC, `Verk` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `Fremført->Artist`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Artist` )
    REFERENCES `Artist` (`ArtistNavn` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Fremført->Spor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Plate` , `Verk` )
    /* Was this intentional, rather than (`Plate`, `Verk`)? */
    /* If not, you must also match the data type of `Plate` VARCHAR(20) to that of Spor.Plate VARCHAR(45) */
    REFERENCES `Spor` (`Verk` , `Verk` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

As noted above, if the constraint `Fremført->Spor` was intended to reference `Spor (Plate , Verk )` instead of `Spor (Verk , Verk )` as you have defined it, then you will also encounter an err150 due to the type mismatch between `Spor.Plate` and `Fremført.Plate`.  Change `Fremført.Plate` to `VARCHAR(45)`.

Comment: I changed all data types to VARCHAR(45) but it still gives an error. 

This is the relational schema given for the assignment:
http://ptpimg.me/edptp1.png

I must have misinterpreted it. The way I read it this means that verk(SPOR) is a key for both plate(FREMFØRT) and verk(FREMFØRT)

Comment: @user1736049 You changed `Artist.ArtistNavn` to `VARCHAR(45)`?

Comment: Yes, all columns for schema, including Artist.ArtistNavn.

Comment: I am convinced it is because of `Spor` (`Verk` , `Verk` ).  There is no index of `Spor` (`Verk` , `Verk` )` on that table, and consequently the FK cannot be create.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I understood your point. How could I not see that myself.. Thanks again. This site is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Error 150 is a foreign key constraint issue. I would suspect that one of the two FK's you have have an issue.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

**(errno: 150)** that error mean that the FK failed so the create table too....

Please review your FK.

- Did you already created it? (the table with the PK pointing to this one)
- Did your spell it right?
- Is it the same data type that the PK?